# Typescript moment date difference

Tags: typescript, momentjs

Im having several issues using moment to calculate the difference in days. Let me expose my problem:

I have to subtract one date from todays date. For example 28/02/2022 - 21/02/2022. Doing this in this way:

```
const timeDifference = moment("28/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY").diff(moment(moment(), "DD/MM/YYYY"), "days");
```

`This returns 6 days` as it doesnt include I believe the last day. Since I need it to include the last day I did the following:

```
const timeDifference = moment("21/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY")
            .add(1, 'days')
            .diff(moment(moment(), "DD/MM/YYYY"), "days");
```

`This now returns 7` days which is what I need.

Now the problem is that I have an `if statement` which does the following:

```
if (timeDifference < 0)
```

Now if timeDifference is todays date it returns 0 but if its 20/02/2022 it also returns 0 due to the .add when I need it to return -1.

I was now trying to do a different approach to do this if by doing

```
if (moment("20/02/2022") < moment.utc()) {
```

but this is not working when the date is less than todays date it will enter the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is this :

```
moment("28/02/2022", "DD/MM/YYYY").diff(moment().startOf('day'), 'days')
```

By the way, no need for that double moment() in the diff, ass `diff` takes `moment` instance what ever the source.